# Understanding classification results

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I've run a simple two-class neural network where I got this result in the end (eval):

[image]

I think I am going to be happy with the `True Positive` and `False Negative` results. But what does `False Positive` mean? `False Positive` means it did not correctly classify 2002 elements and missed them?

The `Accuracy` is 66%, that's really bad right? Whats the difference between that and `AUC`?

`Precision` suffers because Accuracy also is bad (I hoping for a 80%+)?

And how do I flip `Positive Label` and `Negative Label`? I really want to predict the classification where the target is to find `CANDIDATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, for the false/true positives and false/true negatives :
You have detected almost all the CANDIDATE samples in your dataset, 3420 of them were correctly predicted as TRUE and 31 of them were predicted as FALSE. This information is captured in the Recall ratio : 3420/(3420+31) = 99.1%. It is very high, so very good.

However, you have predicted **too many** CANDIDATE. Indeed, in all the TRUE values predicted by the model, 3420 were actually TRUE and 2002 were actually FALSE. This makes the Precision ratio bad : 3420/(3420+2002)=63.1%. Which is not that good.

F1 is a combinaison between Precision and Recall, it summarizes them into one value, some kind of weighted average. The formula is 2*(P*R)/(P+R). So if one of Precision or Recall is bad : the F1score will capture it.

You can see that you have a total of 5999 examples in your data set. Out of those, 3451 are really TRUE and 2548 are really FALSE. So you have 57% of your data that is TRUE. If you make a really stupid classifier that classifies everything as TRUE whatever the features are, then you will get 57% accuracy. Given that, 66.1% accuracy is not really good. 
If you look at the second column of that table, you only predict 577 FALSE out of the 5999 samples. Your classifier is heavily biased towards TRUE predictions.

For the AUC, it stands for Area Under the Curve. You can read [more detailed info about it here](http://fastml.com/what-you-wanted-to-know-about-auc/). To summarize : when you predic a value, you don't really get True or False directly. You get a real number between 0 (False) and 1 (True). The way to classify a predicted value, say 0.2, is to use a Threshold. The threshold is by default set to 0.5. So if you predict 0.2, your model will predict to classify it as a False because 0.2<0.5. But you could make that treshold move between 0 and 1. If the classifier is really good, if it discriminates really well the Falses and Trues predictions, then the AUC will be close to 1. If it's really bad, it will be close to 0.5. Refer to the link if you need more information.

Comment: Did that help?!